# Illegal State Exception: Custom Dialog

Tags: android

I have created a custom dialog layout. When invoked, the dialog pops up fine. But when I try to set the content inside the dialog using the two lines commented below, it throws an illegal state exception.

```
 private void showCustomDialog(String content){
     final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
     d.setContentView(R.layout.spread_info_popup);
     d.show();

     // TextView contentTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_dialog_content);
     // contentTv.setText(content);

     }
```

What is wrong here ?

Do i need to inflate the layout `spread_info_popup` before referring to `TextView` within it with an id of `my_dialog_content` ?

the Stacktrace:

```
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     ... 11 more
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.me.reader.ui.activity.CompleteList.showSpreadInfoPopup(CompleteList.java:122)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.me.reader.ui.activity.CompleteList.setSpreadDescriptionfromXML(CompleteList.java:104)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     at com.me.reader.ui.activity.CompleteList.onAboutIconClicked(CompleteList.java:81)
03-04 15:03:54.690: E/AndroidRuntime(4194):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: what you need to do is post the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should look for the view inside the Dialog:

```
   TextView contentTv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_dialog_content);
   contentTv.setText(content);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById%28int%29) the documentation.

Comment: should it not be `NullPointerException`??

Comment: there is no need to read the Stacktrace. it is a NPE for sure

Comment: yes but op says "throws an illegal state exception"

Comment: thanks that was the precise issue, but it was for sure an IllegalStateException not NullPointerException. Solved :)

Comment: you are right, he says so, but that snippet can not throw IllegalStateException

Comment: Probably `onClick()` via reflection, outermost exception is `IllegalStateException`, caused by NPE

Comment: Ok as an update the exception was "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" but down below in the stack trace it said "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @laalto yes it could be, but without having the whole picture it is impossible to understand what is/was going on. Still that's not the signature need for the android:onClick property.